# GIt LFS is very slow

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

We are currently in the process of getting years of Art source files into several new Github repositories. A lot of these files are really big so obviously Git LFS is supposed to be the way to go.
Adding all the files to LFS is ok, uploading about 6 Gb (4000 files) of data took about 30 minutes. That is quite acceptable for that size.
Pulling the data on a different machine though took over 2 hours. And this is our smallest Art repository. That is not acceptable for that size, especially when our download speed is a lot higher then our upload speed.

As this has to be done by our Art team, we have been using SourceTree for Pushing and Pulling the LFS Repositories. The Command line is just not acceptable for use by them, so options of disabling Smut before the pull isn't really possible.

Is there anyway we can speed up the pull/fetch process? Or are we better off storing our art data in a non-git System?

Edit: We are storing them on Github.com. We have created a brand new repository, enabled LFS on it and added all the files to LFS. I am working on a brand new SSD. I doubt it's the fastest SSD, but it should be a lot faster then my download speed

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? Where are you storing your GitLFS files on the server side: is that on github.com or somewhere else? Did you move all the large files over to LFS with `git lfs migrate`? If I recall correctly, it is still downloading all files one by one and not in a single stream, thus being slow. Heavily depends on your own disk speed as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, We are storing them on Github.com. We have created a brand new repository, enabled LFS on it and added all the files to LFS. I am working on a brand new SSD. I doubt it's the fastest SSD, but it should be a lot faster then my download speed

Comment: What version of Git LFS and Git are you using?  Do you see the same problem from the command line, even if you don't want to use it?  If so, what kind of output do you get from the clone or checkout command?

Comment: I had already upgraded git to version 2.34. 
A test with "git lfs pull" from the command line did complete in approx. 16 minutes. This is fine. So the problem is more with SourceTree then rather then Git. I have modified SourceTree to use the installed Git version rather then it's internal one. Opening the repository in SourceTree it says there are a lot of changes now. I guess SourceTree isn't working properly with LFS? Does anyone have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Late to the party, but for anyone else who stumbles across the question.  I would store your art in a non-git system.  Due to its underlying design Git really shines for text files, but provides sub-par performance for binary files and large files in general (hence the need for lfs).  When dealing with large/binary files select a repository that supports partial checkouts, and stores diffs of binary files on the server (although depending on your image formats, the diffs may be close to the size of the images themselves).